# Can JavaScript set the mime type on window.open

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I am trying to open a debug window within Javascript. Javascript will pass the debug window a JSON string which [JSONView (a Chrome extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) should display in a nicely formatted way.

For this to work the MIME type must be "`application/json`".  Is it possible to send the mime type and JSON string to `window.open` as a parameter some how?  I think the MIME type and content has to be set on window.open otherwise JSONView won't get triggered.

I did try this, but it did not work:

```
var x = window.open("about:blank", 'x'); 
var doc = x.document; 
doc.open("application/json"); 
doc.write($(".trend_chart").attr("data-trendChart"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document that your opening should be of type "`application/json`" you cannot send it as a parameter in the [`window.open` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) since it's out of context. The browser instead is the one that determines the file type using the request headers.

```
window.open("http://www.yoursite.com/file.json", "mywindow");
```

You should see the json file within JSONView without problems. If the browser still asks you to download the file, your installation of JSONView is probably broken.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

You'd be better off doing:

```
console.log(JSON.parse($(".trend_chart").attr("data-trendChart")));
```