# Display pdf in browser with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

PHP code generates pdf content(using mpdf).I need to display it in browser using js (ajax request gets this pdf content as string). How can I do this?

PHP:

```
$data['content'] = utf8_encode($this->_getViewPDF($data['content']));
```

JS:

```
var jsonString = utf8_decode(data.content);
var template = "<object type='application/pdf' data= '" + jsonString + "'>";
var windowPrint,
objBrowse = window.navigator;

windowPrint = window.open('', '_blank');

windowPrint.document.write(template);
windowPrint.document.close();
windowPrint.focus();
```

But browser displays only pdf code

Comment: Was there anything wrong with the 43,300,000 results returned for a Google search on [display pdf with javascript](https://www.google.com.au/#q=display+pdf+with+javascript)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript set the mime type on window.open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707957/can-javascript-set-the-mime-type-on-window-open)

Comment: I have read a lot of posts, but I didn't found how to display pdf from base64 code

Comment: @AlexK: Have you tried with [RFC 2397](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397)? Those could work with `window.open` as those URIs can ship a mime-type. But I'm just guessing, you need to do further research.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a PDF file into a temporary file accessible via a URL from your web server, and then have the script send back the URL for accessing that file.

Refer links below

[using AJAX and Jquery to create pdf using FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209897/using-ajax-and-jquery-to-create-pdf-using-fpdf)

[XMLHttpRequest to open PDF in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750461/xmlhttprequest-to-open-pdf-in-browser/4750685#4750685)