# Using HTML, How do I open a file as an excel file?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have an excel file named **new.xls** which I have saved in **.html** format as **new.html** . I have removed the extension so the filename is just **`new`**

Now if I rename the file to **new.xls** .
For the following code,

`<input type="button" onclick='window.open("new.xls")' value="Open File">`

The resultant file opens in Excel.

Then if I rename the file to **new.html**
For the following code

`<input type="button" onclick='window.open("new.html")' value="Open File">`

The resultant file will open in the browser as a table.

I want to keep the file name as **new** and use two different buttons, one to open the file in Excel and the other to open the file in browser as html. 
Trick the browser into thinking that the file is a **.xls** or **.html** file

I tried with the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
    <input type="button" onclick="openxls()" value="Open File as xls ">
    <input type="button" onclick="openhtml()" value="Open File as html">
</body>
<script>
    function openxls()
        {
         var x = ".xls" 
         var y = "new" + x ;
         window.open(y);
        }

            function openhtml()
        {
         var x = ".html" 
         var y = "new" + x ;
         window.open(y);
        }
</script>
</html>
```

But I got results like

> Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/daniel/Desktop/new.xls.
>
> File not found
>   Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/daniel/Desktop/new.html.

Please help

When i do `var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});`

The result is

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta name="Excel Workbook Frameset">
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 12">
<link rel=File-List href="new_files/filelist.xml">
<![if !supportTabStrip]>
<link id="shLink" href="new_files/sheet001.htm">

<link id="shLink">

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
 var c_lTabs=1;

 var c_rgszSh=new Array(c_lTabs);
 c_rgszSh[0] = "Sample-spreadsheet-file";



 var c_rgszClr=new Array(8);
 c_rgszClr[0]="window";
 c_rgszClr[1]="buttonface";
 c_rgszClr[2]="windowframe";
 c_rgszClr[3]="windowtext";
 c_rgszClr[4]="threedlightshadow";
 c_rgszClr[5]="threedhighlight";
 c_rgszClr[6]="threeddarkshadow";
 c_rgszClr[7]="threedshadow";

 var g_iShCur;
 var g_rglTabX=new Array(c_lTabs);

function fnGetIEVer()
{
 var ua=window.navigator.userAgent
 var msie=ua.indexOf("MSIE")
 if (msie>0 && window.navigator.platform=="Win32")
  return parseInt(ua.substring(msie+5,ua.indexOf(".", msie)));
 else
  return 0;
}

function fnBuildFrameset()
{
 var szHTML="<frameset rows=\"*,18\" border=0 width=0 frameborder=no framespacing=0>"+
  "<frame src=\""+document.all.item("shLink")[0].href+"\" name=\"frSheet\" noresize>"+
  "<frameset cols=\"54,*\" border=0 width=0 frameborder=no framespacing=0>"+
  "<frame src=\"\" name=\"frScroll\" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no>"+
  "<frame src=\"\" name=\"frTabs\" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no>"+
  "</frameset></frameset><plaintext>";

 with (document) {
  open("text/html","replace");
  write(szHTML);
  close();
 }

 fnBuildTabStrip();
}

function fnBuildTabStrip()
{
 var szHTML=
  "<html><head><style>.clScroll {font:8pt Courier New;color:"+c_rgszClr[6]+";cursor:default;line-height:10pt;}"+
  ".clScroll2 {font:10pt Arial;color:"+c_rgszClr[6]+";cursor:default;line-height:11pt;}</style></head>"+
  "<body onclick=\"event.returnValue=false;\" ondragstart=\"event.returnValue=false;\" onselectstart=\"event.returnValue=false;\" bgcolor="+c_rgszClr[4]+" topmargin=0 leftmargin=0><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>"+
  "<tr><td colspan=6 height=1 bgcolor="+c_rgszClr[2]+"></td></tr>"+
  "<tr><td style=\"font:1pt\">&nbsp;<td>"+
  "<td valign=top id=tdScroll class=\"clScroll\" onclick=\"parent.fnFastScrollTabs(0);\" onmouseover=\"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(0);\" onmouseout=\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(0);\"><a>&#171;</a></td>"+
  "<td valign=top id=tdScroll class=\"clScroll2\" onclick=\"parent.fnScrollTabs(0);\" ondblclick=\"parent.fnScrollTabs(0);\" onmouseover=\"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(1);\" onmouseout=\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(1);\"><a>&lt</a></td>"+
  "<td valign=top id=tdScroll class=\"clScroll2\" onclick=\"parent.fnScrollTabs(1);\" ondblclick=\"parent.fnScrollTabs(1);\" onmouseover=\"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(2);\" onmouseout=\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(2);\"><a>&gt</a></td>"+
  "<td valign=top id=tdScroll class=\"clScroll\" onclick=\"parent.fnFastScrollTabs(1);\" onmouseover=\"parent.fnMouseOverScroll(3);\" onmouseout=\"parent.fnMouseOutScroll(3);\"><a>&#187;</a></td>"+
  "<td style=\"font:1pt\">&nbsp;<td></tr></table></body></html>";

 with (frames['frScroll'].document) {
  open("text/html","replace");
  write(szHTML);
  close();
 }

 szHTML =
  "<html><head>"+
  "<style>A:link,A:visited,A:active {text-decoration:none;"+"color:"+c_rgszClr[3]+";}"+
  ".clTab {cursor:hand;background:"+c_rgszClr[1]+";font:9pt Arial;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;text-align:center;}"+
  ".clBorder {background:"+c_rgszClr[2]+";font:1pt;}"+
  "</style></head><body onload=\"parent.fnInit();\" onselectstart=\"event.returnValue=false;\" ondragstart=\"event.returnValue=false;\" bgcolor="+c_rgszClr[4]+
  " topmargin=0 leftmargin=0><table id=tbTabs cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>";

 var iCellCount=(c_lTabs+1)*2;

 var i;
 for (i=0;i<iCellCount;i+=2)
  szHTML+="<col width=1><col>";

 var iRow;
 for (iRow=0;iRow<6;iRow++) {

  szHTML+="<tr>";

  if (iRow==5)
   szHTML+="<td colspan="+iCellCount+"></td>";
  else {
   if (iRow==0) {
    for(i=0;i<iCellCount;i++)
     szHTML+="<td height=1 class=\"clBorder\"></td>";
   } else if (iRow==1) {
    for(i=0;i<c_lTabs;i++) {
     szHTML+="<td height=1 nowrap class=\"clBorder\">&nbsp;</td>";
     szHTML+=
      "<td id=tdTab height=1 nowrap class=\"clTab\" onmouseover=\"parent.fnMouseOverTab("+i+");\" onmouseout=\"parent.fnMouseOutTab("+i+");\">"+
      "<a href=\""+document.all.item("shLink")[i].href+"\" target=\"frSheet\" id=aTab>&nbsp;"+c_rgszSh[i]+"&nbsp;</a></td>";
    }
    szHTML+="<td id=tdTab height=1 nowrap class=\"clBorder\"><a id=aTab>&nbsp;</a></td><td width=100%></td>";
   } else if (iRow==2) {
    for (i=0;i<c_lTabs;i++)
     szHTML+="<td height=1></td><td height=1 class=\"clBorder\"></td>";
    szHTML+="<td height=1></td><td height=1></td>";
   } else if (iRow==3) {
    for (i=0;i<iCellCount;i++)
     szHTML+="<td height=1></td>";
   } else if (iRow==4) {
    for (i=0;i<c_lTabs;i++)
     szHTML+="<td height=1 width=1></td><td height=1></td>";
    szHTML+="<td height=1 width=1></td><td></td>";
   }
  }
  szHTML+="</tr>";
 }

 szHTML+="</table></body></html>";
 with (frames['frTabs'].document) {
  open("text/html","replace");
  charset=document.charset;
  write(szHTML);
  close();
 }
}

function fnInit()
{
 g_rglTabX[0]=0;
 var i;
 for (i=1;i<=c_lTabs;i++)
  with (frames['frTabs'].document.all.tbTabs.rows[1].cells[fnTabToCol(i-1)])
   g_rglTabX[i]=offsetLeft+offsetWidth-6;
}

function fnTabToCol(iTab)
{
 return 2*iTab+1;
}

function fnNextTab(fDir)
{
 var iNextTab=-1;
 var i;

 with (frames['frTabs'].document.body) {
  if (fDir==0) {
   if (scrollLeft>0) {
    for (i=0;i<c_lTabs&&g_rglTabX[i]<scrollLeft;i++);
    if (i<c_lTabs)
     iNextTab=i-1;
   }
  } else {
   if (g_rglTabX[c_lTabs]+6>offsetWidth+scrollLeft) {
    for (i=0;i<c_lTabs&&g_rglTabX[i]<=scrollLeft;i++);
    if (i<c_lTabs)
     iNextTab=i;
   }
  }
 }
 return iNextTab;
}

function fnScrollTabs(fDir)
{
 var iNextTab=fnNextTab(fDir);

 if (iNextTab>=0) {
  frames['frTabs'].scroll(g_rglTabX[iNextTab],0);
  return true;
 } else
  return false;
}

function fnFastScrollTabs(fDir)
{
 if (c_lTabs>16)
  frames['frTabs'].scroll(g_rglTabX[fDir?c_lTabs-1:0],0);
 else
  if (fnScrollTabs(fDir)>0) window.setTimeout("fnFastScrollTabs("+fDir+");",5);
}

function fnSetTabProps(iTab,fActive)
{
 var iCol=fnTabToCol(iTab);
 var i;

 if (iTab>=0) {
  with (frames['frTabs'].document.all) {
   with (tbTabs) {
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++) {
     with (rows[i]) {
      if (i==0)
       cells[iCol].style.background=c_rgszClr[fActive?0:2];
      else if (i>0 && i<4) {
       if (fActive) {
        cells[iCol-1].style.background=c_rgszClr[2];
        cells[iCol].style.background=c_rgszClr[0];
        cells[iCol+1].style.background=c_rgszClr[2];
       } else {
        if (i==1) {
         cells[iCol-1].style.background=c_rgszClr[2];
         cells[iCol].style.background=c_rgszClr[1];
         cells[iCol+1].style.background=c_rgszClr[2];
        } else {
         cells[iCol-1].style.background=c_rgszClr[4];
         cells[iCol].style.background=c_rgszClr[(i==2)?2:4];
         cells[iCol+1].style.background=c_rgszClr[4];
        }
       }
      } else
       cells[iCol].style.background=c_rgszClr[fActive?2:4];
     }
    }
   }
   with (aTab[iTab].style) {
    cursor=(fActive?"default":"hand");
    color=c_rgszClr[3];
   }
  }
 }
}

function fnMouseOverScroll(iCtl)
{
 frames['frScroll'].document.all.tdScroll[iCtl].style.color=c_rgszClr[7];
}

function fnMouseOutScroll(iCtl)
{
 frames['frScroll'].document.all.tdScroll[iCtl].style.color=c_rgszClr[6];
}

function fnMouseOverTab(iTab)
{
 if (iTab!=g_iShCur) {
  var iCol=fnTabToCol(iTab);
  with (frames['frTabs'].document.all) {
   tdTab[iTab].style.background=c_rgszClr[5];
  }
 }
}

function fnMouseOutTab(iTab)
{
 if (iTab>=0) {
  var elFrom=frames['frTabs'].event.srcElement;
  var elTo=frames['frTabs'].event.toElement;

  if ((!elTo) ||
   (elFrom.tagName==elTo.tagName) ||
   (elTo.tagName=="A" && elTo.parentElement!=elFrom) ||
   (elFrom.tagName=="A" && elFrom.parentElement!=elTo)) {

   if (iTab!=g_iShCur) {
    with (frames['frTabs'].document.all) {
     tdTab[iTab].style.background=c_rgszClr[1];
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

function fnSetActiveSheet(iSh)
{
 if (iSh!=g_iShCur) {
  fnSetTabProps(g_iShCur,false);
  fnSetTabProps(iSh,true);
  g_iShCur=iSh;
 }
}

 window.g_iIEVer=fnGetIEVer();
 if (window.g_iIEVer>=4)
  fnBuildFrameset();
//-->
</script>
<![endif]><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Sample-spreadsheet-file</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetSource HRef="new_files/sheet001.htm"/>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
  <x:Stylesheet HRef="new_files/stylesheet.css"/>
  <x:WindowHeight>11745</x:WindowHeight>
  <x:WindowWidth>20730</x:WindowWidth>
  <x:WindowTopX>-15</x:WindowTopX>
  <x:WindowTopY>0</x:WindowTopY>
  <x:Calculation>ManualCalculation</x:Calculation>
  <x:MaxChange>0.0001</x:MaxChange>
  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<frameset rows="*,39" border=0 width=0 frameborder=no framespacing=0>
 <frame src="new_files/sheet001.htm" name="frSheet">
 <frame src="new_files/tabstrip.htm" name="frTabs" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>
 <noframes>
  <body>
   <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
  </body>
 </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have two saved files at filesystem? `new.xls` and `new.html`? Or only single file named `new`?

Comment: @guest271314......Just one file `new` . Without any extension.

Comment: What is the `MIME` type of `new` file at filesystem? Why do you not want to use two separate files?

Comment: @guest271314....not sure ....its `mimeTypes.rdf`....Im using firefox

Comment: If you open file manager window at os and review file properties, what is the file type of `new`? What is issue with creating two separate files? That is `new.xls` and `new.html`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript set the mime type on window.open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707957/can-javascript-set-the-mime-type-on-window-open)

Comment: I do not want to use two separate files coz , I want to open the file in excel to edit and I want it to preview on the browser. I do not know how to synchronise the two files.

Comment: After editing at excel, you should be able to request `new.xls` as a `Blob` using `XMLHttpRequest()`, create a new `Blob` from response with `type` set to `text/html`, then use `URL.createObjectURL()` with newly created `Blob` as parameter passed to `window.open()` to view file at browser as a `.html` document. Will post this approach as a possible Answer

Comment: @enhzflep Note, it is possible to create `Blob` or `File` object with `MIME` type set to a different `MIME` type than original file or document, before passing file object with adjusted `MIME` type to `window.open()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to open the file in excel to edit and I want it to preview on
>   the browser.

After editing at excel, you should be able to request `new.xls` as a `Blob` using `XMLHttpRequest()` with `.responseType` set to `"blob"`, create a new `Blob` from response with `type` set to `text/html`, then use `URL.createObjectURL()` with newly created `Blob` as parameter passed to `window.open()` to view file at browser as a `.html` document.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "new.xls");
request.responseType = "blob";
request.onload = function() {
  // set `blob` `type` to `"text/html"`
  var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type:"text/html"});
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var w = window.open(url);
}
request.send();
```

Comment: does'nt work, the first time i tried, it displayed only html  text. Second time its all blank

Comment: @DannyBoi _"it displayed only html text"_  Can you include html text that is displayed, and text of `new.xls` at Question?

Comment: @DannyBoi Note, has been a while since used excel. Though believe openoffice has available plugins to convert from `.xls` to `.html`

Comment: Excel has a save to Other Formats option
the file is parsing through properly i think , I did `type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8" ` and its displaying html code.

Comment: @DannyBoi _"and its displaying html code."_ Can you include the `html` at Question? The `html` is not rendered as `html` at newly opened `window`?

Comment: I have edited.
 ` the first time i tried, it displayed only html text.` >>> i dnt hv screenshot but it is like displaying all data without columns

Comment: @DannyBoi Screenshots of text does usually help resolve issue. Actual text could possibly help.  If you change the file extension to `.html` the document is rendered with columns? Not sure what you mean by "without" columns? The simplest approach would be to convert document to `.html`, then view in browser

Comment: @DannyBoi The document has syntax errors. At first glance, missing quotes at attributes of `<frameset>` elements, also `<body>` element is child of `<frameset>` elements. If you load the `html` at plnkr http://plnkr.co editor the syntax error should be highlighted.

Comment: I didnt make that document, it is autogenerated by excel. btw like another html files it has a folder attached along with it. `new_files`

Comment: @DannyBoi _"I didnt make that document, it is autogenerated by excel"_ The document contains invalid `html`. Not sure what you mean by "a folder attached". If excel offer a way to convert the file to valid `html`, that would be simplest option to resolve issue. Or manually correct syntax errors and links to external files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122607/discussion-between-dannyboi-and-guest271314).

Comment: Your answer actually works, I took another html file and it works perfectly fine.