# How to open excel file directly in any browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, excel

I tried some code to open directly excel file in javascript but chrome doesn't supported 'ActiveXObject'.

the code is only supported in IE.

```
function openFile(strFilePath)
    {
    var objExcel;
            //Create EXCEL object
    objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    objExcel.Visible = true;
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strLocation, false, false);
}
```

is there any solution to implement this code in any browser? or other solution to solve this issue.

Comment: I think [Its help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39315263)

Comment: Just need to provide the file URL in anchor tag or window.open() and browser will automatically open it.